# Pod file keeps disappearing after some time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have IronSourceSDK pod files installed in my project and everything compiles and runs great. However, when I'm done for the day and pick it up the next day, I always get a compile error that the pod this file is missing -

> :0: error: error opening input file '.../Pods/IronSourceSDK/IronSource/IronSource.framework/Versions/A/Headers/IronSource.h' (No such file or directory)

So every day I re-install the pods and it's back to normal until the next day.

I used Firebase SDK before and exactly the same thing used to happen.

What causes this deletion of the header file?

**EDIT**:

As requested, here is how my Podfile looks like:

```
 platform :ios, '10.0'

 target 'testGame' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for testGame

 pod 'IronSourceSDK','6.17.0.0'
 pod 'IronSourceAdMobAdapter','4.3.12.0'
 pod 'IronSourceFacebookAdapter','4.3.16.0'
 pod 'SVProgressHUD'
 pod 'FBAudienceNetwork'
 pod 'Firebase/Core'
  
  target 'testGameTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'testGameUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

**EDIT 2**:

Here is log of an error:

```
PrecompileSwiftBridgingHeader normal arm64 (in target 'testGame' from project 'testGame')
    cd /Users/admin/Documents/Projects/testGame
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -target arm64-apple-ios11.0 -Xllvm -aarch64-use-tbi -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.6.sdk -I /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FBSDKCoreKit -F /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseCore -F /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -F /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseInstallations -F /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleDataTransport -F /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport -F /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleUtilities -F /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PromisesObjC -F /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SVProgressHUD -F /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/nanopb -F /Users/admin/Documents/Projects/testGame/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/Static -F /Users/admin/Documents/Projects/testGame/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F /Users/admin/Documents/Projects/testGame/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFramework-Current -F /Users/admin/Documents/Projects/testGame/Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks -F /Users/admin/Documents/Projects/testGame/Pods/IronSourceAdMobAdapter/ISAdMobAdapter -F /Users/admin/Documents/Projects/testGame/Pods/IronSourceFacebookAdapter/ISFacebookAdapter -F /Users/admin/Documents/Projects/testGame/Pods/IronSourceSDK/IronSource -enable-testing -g -module-cache-path /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -swift-version 4.2 -enforce-exclusivity=checked -Onone -D DEBUG -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -working-directory -Xcc /Users/admin/Documents/Projects/testGame -enable-anonymous-context-mangled-names -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Intermediates.noindex/testGame.build/Debug-iphoneos/testGame.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Intermediates.noindex/testGame.build/Debug-iphoneos/testGame.build/testGame-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Intermediates.noindex/testGame.build/Debug-iphoneos/testGame.build/testGame-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Intermediates.noindex/testGame.build/Debug-iphoneos/testGame.build/testGame-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Intermediates.noindex/testGame.build/Debug-iphoneos/testGame.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Intermediates.noindex/testGame.build/Debug-iphoneos/testGame.build/testGame-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseInstallations/FirebaseInstallations.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PromisesObjC/FBLPromises.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/nanopb/nanopb.framework/Headers -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Documents/Projects/testGame/Pods/Headers/Public -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Documents/Projects/testGame/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Documents/Projects/testGame/Pods/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources -Xcc -I/Sources/FBLPromises/include -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Intermediates.noindex/testGame.build/Debug-iphoneos/testGame.build/DerivedSources-normal/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Intermediates.noindex/testGame.build/Debug-iphoneos/testGame.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Intermediates.noindex/testGame.build/Debug-iphoneos/testGame.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DFBSDKCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DPB_FIELD_32BIT=1 -Xcc -DPB_NO_PACKED_STRUCTS=1 -Xcc -DPB_ENABLE_MALLOC=1 -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/IronSource-2INEYF37VVZFN.dia /Users/admin/Documents/Projects/testGame/Pods/IronSourceSDK/IronSource/IronSource.framework/Versions/A/Headers/IronSource.h -index-store-path /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Index/DataStore -emit-pch -pch-output-dir /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testGame-hjvcsuwthrlgqvgzoiwufxyfpede/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders
```

Comment: can you share your Podfile here? Also, make sure you open the .xcworkspace and not .xcodeproj file when opening your project.

Comment: Added it in the edit. Yes I am opening .xcworkspace, all pods function properly for certain random periods of time (it can be few hours (pod is removed after running a project on a device randomly) or a full day until I pick it up next day after computer was on sleep mode overnight).

Comment: Do you have installed any software for cleaning cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the project folder was mistakenly stored in iCloud drive due to previous device migration. By plugging in the mobile device each time for testing, data back-up tried to refresh the Pod files but couldn't find them, so they were stuck at status - "Waiting for Download, which then became unrecognizable by Xcode.

Localizing the project folder and removing cloud dependency solved the problem.